# Is "reverse homology" $\ker g \subset \text{im} f$ possible?

Tags: algebraic-topology, modules, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

[$\forall$ has $\exists$ as a "left adjoint" in Topos Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_quantification#As_adjoint).

Let $M \xrightarrow{f} M' \xrightarrow{g} M''$  be  sequence of $A$-modules and $A$-module homomorphisms.  Now suppose we don't have $gf = 0$ or in other words no ability to compute traditional Homology at $M'$, but instead we have sort of an adjoint opposite:

$$
\forall x \in \ker g, \exists y \in M : f(y) = x
$$

which leads to $gf(y) = 0$.  In other words, we're dealing with instead of traditional homology as $\text{im}f \subset \ker g$, the opposite inclusion $\ker g \subset \text{im} f$.

There can be long sequences of these types of "reverse complexes" in practice, since *any sequence of surjections* and *any sequence of injections* is of this type, but it of course probably occurs  outside of those as well.

**Do any techniques from traditional (forward) homology carry over to this "reverse homology"?**

Note that a sequence is exact in this "reverse homology" if and only if it is exact in homology.

Since we could define this reverse homology, then we could define "negative dimension".  So in other words perhaps have mixed sequences of forward and reverse homologies, where exactness has dimension zero, wherever dimension is defined such as on vector spaces.

Comment: I haven’t checked, but if this reverse homology isn’t suitably functorial then it isn’t likely to be useful.

Comment: Also, ordinary homology already allows for negative grading.

Comment: @Randall is that the same things as the underlying reverse inclusion of the two submodules $\ker, \text{im}$?

Comment: No.  There’s just nothing prohibiting a chain complex from being graded by negative integers.

Comment: @Randall I argue then that this is more natural (accessible) to beginners of Hom. Algebra.

Comment: @Randall I thought the grading stays the same (the indexing of the modules), so this is not related to that, or maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: I don’t find it more natural, mainly because I don’t see any application of it.  Are there any?

Comment: @Randall I'm looking at modular arithmetic rings (quotients of the integers) and when you connect them with infinite non-trivial map sequences where possible, they don't satisfy traditional chain map property, but they do satisfy this reverse property.  For example $\Bbb{Z}/p^2 \to \Bbb{Z}/p$ ad infinitum in the powers of a number $p$, or even $\Bbb{Z}/p \to \Bbb{Z}/p^2$ that is multiplication by $p$ or injections.

Comment: Writing up an example of that in your question would be very helpful with the context.

Comment: @Randall see my edited comment.  I can't find any "infinite chain map sequence" related to powers of a modulus with these objects, but you *can* do it if there were a "reverse homology" since infinite sequences of surjections or injections satisfy it trivially (by that I mean $\ker  = 0$ or $\text{im} = $ the whole space).  I know of the basic short exact sequences, but I wanted to form *infinite* double, triple, or higher complex of modular arithmetic rings.  It's possible potentially with this reverse homology but not with traditional homology (the infinite part isn't unless objects vanish).

Comment: Are you sure you don't want [inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_limit)/[direct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_limit) limits instead?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I'm sure, I want double, triple, and higher complexes of an infinite grid of  the modular arithmetic rings, indexed by powers of the moduli.

Comment: @Randall Thank you for your first suggestion and see my answer below.  I will accept any other answers that can provide answers to the further questions therein, or other words provide more examples of application, now that we know that we do have functoriality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We define a **reverse chain complex** $X_{\bullet}$ of $A$-modules and $A$-module homomorphisms $d_{i} : X_i \to X_{i-1}$ to be a usual chain complex of $A$-modules except the condition $\operatorname{im} d_i \subset \ker d_{i-1}$ gets reversed, that is: $\ker d_{i-1} \subset \operatorname{im} d_i$.

On any reverse chain complex $X_{\bullet}$ with differential $d_{i}$, we define   the **$i$th reverse homology module** by $H_i(X) := \dfrac{\operatorname{im}d_{i+1}}{\ker d_i}$.  Just as in usual homology we define the **module of $i$-cycles** by $Z_i(X) := \ker d_i$ and the **module of $i$-boundaries** by $B_i(X) := \operatorname{im} d_{i+1}$.  If $\alpha : X_{\bullet} \to Y_{\bullet}$ is a morphism of reverse chain complexes, then we get an **induced canonical homomorphism** $H_i(\alpha) : H_i(X) \to H_i(Y)$ (reading from Lang's Algebra).

*Proof.* The same as in usual chain complexes, $\alpha$ takes $i$-cycles of $X$ into $i$-cycles of $Y$ and $i$-boundaries of $X$ into $i$-boundaries of $Y$.  So that if $\overline{x} \in H_i(X)$, then $\overline{x} = x + Z_i(X)$ for some $x \in \operatorname{im} d_{i+1}$.  Define $H_i(\alpha)(\overline{x}) := \alpha(x) + Z_i(Y)$.  Then $H_i(\alpha)$ is well-defined, for if $\overline{x} = \overline{y}$, then $x - y \in Z_i(X)$ which means $\alpha(x) - \alpha(y) \in Z_i(Y)$ by the first sentence.  We have that $H_i(\alpha)$ is an $A$-module homomorphism since $$H_i(\alpha)(\overline{x} + \overline{y}) = H_i(\alpha)(\overline{x + y}) = \alpha(x + y) + Z_i(Y) = \alpha(x) + \alpha(y) + Z_i(Y) = (\alpha(x) + Z_i(Y)) + (\alpha(y) + Z_i(Y)) = H_i(\alpha)(\overline{x}) + H_i(\alpha)(\overline{y})$$

And finally for $\gamma \in A$, we have $H_i(\alpha)(\gamma \overline{x}) = H_i(\alpha)(\overline{\gamma x}) = \alpha(\gamma x) + Z_i(Y) = \gamma \alpha(x) + Z_i(Y) = \gamma H_i(\alpha)(x)$.

---

Furthermore, if $X_{\bullet}$ is a reverse chain complex of $A$-modules and $d_i$ its differential, then a sequence of $A$-modules $H_i(X)$ and maps $H_i(d)$ gets induced.

*Proof.*  Let $\overline{x} = x + Z_i(X)$ and define $H_i(d)(\overline{x}) = d_i(x) + Z_{i-1}(X)$.  Then if $\overline{x} = \overline{y}$, we have $\overline{x - y} = 0$ or $x - y \in Z_i(X)$ so that $d_i(x-y) = 0$ and $d_{i-1}\circ d_i(x - y) = 0$ and so $d_i(x) - d_i(y) \in Z_{i-1}(X)$ and we're done.  We leave it to the reader to prove that $H_i(d)$ so defined is an $A$-module homomorphism.

Thus, we have proven that $H_i(X)$ acts somewhat like the $i$th homology module from  General Homology Theory.

I don't yet know if there is a functor $H$ from the category of $A$-module reverse chain complexes to the category of graded $A$-modules.  Can someone who is more proficient at HA comment or answer?